# Pusher Java Client : Failed to subscribe to a presence channel as well as a private channel at a time

Tags: android, push-notification, pusher

I am using pusher java client (pusher-java-client by mdpye) to develop an android application which is using pusher for push notification. I can successfully subscribe to a presence channel after connecting to the Pusher. Once subscribed to the presence channel, When I try to subscribe to another private channel as well, it is showing an error: Invalid signature: Expected HMAC SHA256 hex digest of xxx:YYYY, but got xxxxxxxxxxxxx (possibly an authentication error).

The point is if there were a problem in authentication, I would not have been able to even connect to the first presence channel. so, what can be the problem?

code snippet:

```
authorizer = new HttpAuthorizer(endpointUrl);
PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions().setEncrypted(true).setAuthorizer(authorizer);
pusher = new Pusher(pusher_key, options);
pusher.getConnection().bind(ConnectionState.ALL, this);
String socketId = pusher.getConnection().getSocketId();
String selfJson = authorizer.authorize(PRESENCE_CHANNEL_NAME, socketId);
presenceChannel = pusher.subscribePresence(PRESENCE_CHANNEL_NAME, presenceEventListener);
notificationChannel = pusher.subscribePrivate(notificationChannelName, notificationEventListener);
```

Answer (score 2):

Channels are authorised independently of each other - a call is made to the `Authorizer` for each private or presence subscription made, it's possible that your endpoint returns a correct result for one and incorrect for the other.

Note that there is a difference in the response required from the authorisation endpoint between private and presence channels, the latter includes data about the user which is not valid in the former. See http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users#implementing_endpoints

Comment: Even if the response required for both channels are different, it should not be a problem because for a presence channel, the client library accepts both the auth token (auth signature) and the user info where as for a private channel, it ignores the user info and only accepts the auth token. so, I am sure that should not be a problem. The error which I am getting is "invalid auth signature". Since I have a common server side code for returning the auth response for both the types of channels, how can it be possible to get correct auth token for presence channel and wrong for the private one?

Comment: See http://pusher.com/docs/auth_signatures, the `user_data` is part of the string to be signed. Specifically, for a private channel, the string to sign is `<socket_id>:<channel_name>`, for presence `<socket_id>:<channel_name>:<JSON encoded user data>`

Comment: How would you ensure the correct info is being based with private/presence channels then?